# Where is return value from function stored

Tags: c#, clr

I've read few articles about stack, heap and how they are used in program execution. [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_memory01122006130034PM/csharp_memory.aspx) is one of them.
It is always said that when calling a function, it's parameters are placed to stack, as well as local variables (strictly saying that's not correct, as Eric Lippert described in [his post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx), but that's not my question now).

My question is **where the return value from function is stored and how is it passed to the caller?** Nobody says it's placed on stack, but still nobody says it's not. Can anybody clarify that?

For example, consider the following function:

```
public DateTime GetTomorrowDate()
{
    return DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date;
}
```

Is my understanding that it will declare a local variable for return value correct? If so, why it isn't destroyed when function returns and it's stack frame destroyed? Is it declared in the caller's stack frame (even if it is not used by a caller)? Or maybe it is stored somewhere in a register (I don't believe that, because there may be not suitable-size register for some custom structure).

Comment: These are implementation details. This function could end up being in-lined as well.

Comment: @Habib, The question is not about this particular function. It's just as an example. My question is to understand how CLR processes that. If there are different possibilities - than in what cases are they applied?

Comment: All the way under the covers, the return value will be stored in a register -- in this case as an address to the underlying implementation of a DateTime.  The CLR will manage the lifetime of the object depending on how long a reference to the returned object is held.

Comment: The return value is stored in registers - on x64 it goes in RAX. On x86, 64-bit structures like `DateTime` are returned in EAX:EDX.

Comment: In the example, there is a method AddFive. Its return value goes to the end of stack (because Int32 is a value type), the same way as it works in C/C++, there is no big difference. The same is for DateTime as it is also a value type. The only difference is that its size is bigger and it allocates more space in the stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several strategies (that I have used).

1. The return value is small enough to fit into a register, and is returned from the function as a value in a register reserved for that purpose. This can be extended to 2 or more registers if needed.
2. The return value is created as a temporary variable on the stack frame of the *caller*. Then a reference (pointer) to the temporary is pushed on the stack so that the return value acts as an extra, out parameter. In some languages that variable appears inside the called function as a named variable ('result'), in others the compiler generates a move to that parameter.
3. Two local variables are created, one inside the function and one outside. The value is copied from one to the other on function exit.
4. The return value is simply created as an extra argument. The value found in that argument is pulled out by the caller before it unwinds the stack.
5. The value is returned in a 'special' register, such as a floating point accumulator.
6. The value is placed in a known location (such as a task frame), from which it can be retrieved later.

There are probably others, but those are a good start.

---

My answer was based on reading the question as wanting a summary of common techniques. In the context of C# it would apply to JIT-generated code, but not the CIL itself.

Typical stack-oriented VM languages (including CIL) return values from functions primarily by leaving them on the stack when the function returns. The arguments sit below that, so some stack cleanup is required after function return.

As @eric says, it's hard to see when this information might be useful. Obviously returning large value types from functions could have performance implications, but that is only as expected.

The CIL is rather well documented, but JIT compilation and possible other mechanisms are not, which would further reduce the usefulness of any such insights.

Comment: Good answer. This is what I expected to hear. I wonder why this isn't documented anywhere at least in blogs (or I simply couldn't find that).

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy: Why should it be documented? What decision are you going to make on the basis of that documentation? There is no requirement that a stack frame be involved *at all*; what happens when you `return` a value from an `async` method?  The result field of the associated `Task` is set; there's no stack or registers involved at all. All these things are implementation details that you are freed from having to worry about.

Comment: @EricLippert, my question arised just out of curiosity and not because I need to make some decisions based on the answer. As you stressed in your blog, storing local variables, class fields etc is also implementation details. But that doesn't stop writing hundreds of articles about that. And I wondered why everybody mentions method parameters and local variables, but ignore return value. I think an article, even small one, describing possible options and which of them are used in some specific version of CLR would be very interesting. Unfortunately I couldn't find that.

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy: You are right that this would be a good topic for a blog article. It would be a bad topic for *documentation*: documentation should tell you facts that you can use and rely upon about the public-facing surface of the tool, rather than the interesting implementation details.

Comment: @EricLippert, agree that it shouldn't be an official documentation. I would love to read such post if it existed to extend my understanding of CLR internals. For now david.pfx answer is the best I have on this topic.

Comment: I would be useful to arrange the strategies in a table. As a function of compiler, platform, optimization flags e.t.c. Maybe to add some notable uses as for example, JVM, python env. e.t.c.

Comment: @user1439579: Go for it. Could be a large table.