# What does the compiler do when encountering a return statement?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this code:-

```
int i;
class A
{
public:
    ~A()
    {
        i = 10;
    }
};

int& foo()
{
    i = 3;
    A ob;
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "i = " << foo() << endl; //call to foo
    return 0;
}
```

I'm confused about the order in which the compiler executes this code after encountering the return i statement. 
My guess: 
      A variable of the caller(main) is made(say K) and a reference to it is passed to foo(), when the return statement is encountered, the compiler copies the value of the return statement into K, in this case the address of i, as a reference is being returned. Then it jumps to the end of foo() and the destructor for class object ob is called which changes the value of i to 10. This is followed by the removal of foo() and all its variables(including the reference to K passed to foo) from the call stack and the control is returned to main where K replaces the call to foo() and the cout is implemented. 
Is this the correct order of actions taken by the compiler ?

I searched extensively for what happens in memory when a return is called and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162192/where-is-return-value-from-function-stored) was the best result, though it is for C#.

Comment: The function never went out of scope in the first place. The storage location of the return value is dependent on whatever the compiler made it to be.

Comment: If the same exact principles applied to all programming languages, why would anyone ever become frustrated and decide to create their own?

Comment: @StoryTeller To make others frustrate even more over the new syntax

Comment: I don't think you follow. We corrected the tags because you tagged **wrong**. Don't insist on this, it'll just get your question closed.

Comment: @Neijwiert so *that*'s how Objective-C came to be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `foo` is in scope any place inside this source file, so there's no problem calling it.

As for the reference it's returning, `i` is a file scope variable and thus has static storage duration, which means its lifetime is the life of the program.  This means you're allowed to return a reference to it from `foo`.

Had you attempted to return a reference to a local variable like this:

```
int& foo()
{
    int x = 3;
    return x;
}
```

That would invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since the variable no longer exists after the function exits.

Comment: To add to this answer: The return value != to the actual value of the variable. Which could be anywhere from on the stack to the cpu register. As OP wanted to know the low level stuff about this

Comment: I'm aware of this, what I wanted to know was how the compiler handled this entire process and what changes it makes in memory. I hope my edited question is clearer, sorry for the mistake earlier

Comment: @BamesJond: Compilers are extraordinarily complex, and explaining how they work is the job of a big book, not a SO answer. But you could start by reading the ABI for your platform, as it will discuss how data should be organised during a function call. Either way, this is not about C++ (which is an abstract language for _describing the meaning of programs_)

Comment: Got it @LightnessRacesinOrbit. Thankyou.